# Docker for Windows Containers environment variables

Tags: windows, docker, environment-variables, containers

Ok, this seems easy enough for Linux containers but I am trying to get this done using Windows Containers and its annoying that its so difficult.

I have a Windows Dockerfile which builds a project and part of the build process is to reversion the C# AssemblyInfo.cs files so that the built assemblies have a build version from the CI environment (Devops)

I am using a Powershell script https://github.com/microsoft/psi/blob/master/Build/ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1, it expects 2 Environment variables, one which I can hardcode so is not a problem, but the BUILD_BUILDNUMBER environment variable needs to be injected from Devops build system.

I have tried the following, none of which work

```
ARG BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
ENV BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=$BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
RUN ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1
```

and running

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --build-arg BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=1.2.3.4 .
```

also

```
RUN SETX BUILD_BUILDNUMBER $BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
RUN SETX BUILD_BUILDNUMBER %BUILD_BUILDNUMBER%
```

and a few other combinations that I dont recall, what I ended up doing which works but seems like a hack is to pass the BUILDNUMBER as a file via a COPY and then modifying the the Powershell script to read that into its local variable

So for the moment it works but I would really like to know how this is supposed to work via ARG and ENV for Windows Container builds

Windows Containers definitely feel like Linux containers poor cousin :)

Comment: As far as I can tell ENV just doesn't work in windows docker. It's just broken.  It's not visible to any RUN commands, and the environment variable is not set in the final built image. Its as if ENV has no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Example for CMD in Docker Windows Containers:

```
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://URL.com/_packaging/Name/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"PATForPackages\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN echo %VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt the hard way (can't find that documented anywhere) that environment variables set from outside the container - at least in the case of Windows Containers - are set at the process level. Not at the MACHINE level. The problem with this is that windows containers with several internal moving pieces (IIS, Scheduled Tasks, etc.) I was sort of expecting these env variables to be available system wide, and not just for the entry point or for the remote shell.

Solution.... write a script in your entry point that grabs process level environment variables and propagates them to the system level.